# WARNING: API 'variant.getMappingFile()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMappingFileProvider()'

Tags: android

I just updated Android Studio 3.5 to Android Studio 3.6 and replaced previous Gradle plugin with Gradle plugin 3.6.0 when syncing Gradle:

> build.gradle: API 'variant.getMappingFile()' is obsolete and has been
>   replaced with 'variant.getMappingFileProvider()'

Any suggestions on how to debug this warning. Where is it coming from? I don't see any usage of getMappingFile in my code although, might be some library. Suggestions to debug these kind of cases would be helpful

Comment: Upgrade Your Gradle Like Compile SDK Version, Target SDK Version, Minimum SDK Version & Migrate With AndroidX

Comment: I am already using AndroidX. Why update the minimum SDK Version? Do you mean we stop supporting the older OS version since a newer OS version is released? That doesn't make much sense as we need to support new without breaking old. And can you provide a reason for doing these changes, since the question is about how to diagnose such errors?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When running the gradle script with the parameter `-Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true` set, you can get a stack trace of what is causing the issue.

I found out it in my case was related to Crashlytics. There was this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1276) opened, but it's apparently the legacy-plugin so the issue has been closed again with a suggestion of contacting the Fabric support. So hopefully they will find a solution.

Answer (score 67):

Upgrading

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.29.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
```

in my top-level build.gradle fixed the problem for me.

Comment: just coming from Android Studio 4.0, and that was the same solution.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to build.gradle under Gradle Scripts
2. Add this Line: `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'`
3. Rebuild your Project.

Answer (score 1):

**If your project uses Firebase:** instead of [upgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60436840/4858777) `io.fabric.tools:gradle` version it's better to switch to `com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle` since fabric is deprecated now. See [Upgrade to the Firebase Crashlytics SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk) guide for detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could be of help to someone. In my case, it was:

```
variant.mappingFile
```

which was used in build.gradle to backup mapping files. To remove the warning use:

```
variant.mappingFileProvider
```